# Combo Box carregando valores indesejáveis

Tags: php, html, combobox

Estou com **dois SELECTs** na página que são interdependentes.

No **primeiro** SELECT eu seleciono a Bandeira e no **segundo** todas as lojas que pertencem àquela bandeira. E tenho um **terceiro** campo aonde eu desejo que seja armazenado o ID da loja selecionada. Só que quando eu visualizo no navegador, vêm as duas Caixas Combo (SELECT), mas o campo **INPUT TEXT** não vem.

Quando seleciono a primeira Caixa Combo, a URL retornada é *?fnc=gfi&ans=14&bandorc=47*  e está aparecendo setada automaticamente a empresa 11 no **INPUT TEXT**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando seleciono a segunda Caixa Combo, a URL retornada é *?fnc=gfi&ans=14&emp=4* e está sumindo o **INPUT TEXT**.

Se eu executar a query no PHPMyAdmin o resultado é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código está assim:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>

    <form id="frmCad" name="frmCad" style="float:left; margin-top:0px;" method="post" action="../inc/processa.php?modo=incluir&fnc=<?php echo $fnc; ?>&ans=<?php echo $linha; ?>">
                <p>
        <input name="emp" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $emp; ?>" />
        <input name="projeto" type="hidden" value="Budget" />
        <input name="exercicio" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $basebud; ?>" />
        <input name="linhabud" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $linha; ?>" />
        <input name="usuario" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $usuario; ?>" />      

            <div><label for="nome">Anterior: </label>
<?php

include("../libraries/anterior.php");
?>  

        <fieldset style="padding:8px; margin:15px 0px 25px 0px;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">
            <select name="menu1" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
                <option value="">Selecione a Bandeira</option>
<?php
      $qry="SELECT sjy_empresas.bandeira AS id_bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira
            FROM kcb_tbstates 
            INNER JOIN sjy_bandeira 
            INNER JOIN sjy_grupo 
            INNER JOIN sjy_empresas ON sjy_grupo.id_grupo = sjy_empresas.grupo
            AND sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira = sjy_empresas.bandeira
            AND kcb_tbstates.ID = sjy_empresas.estado
            WHERE sjy_empresas.grupo = '$grupo'
            GROUP BY sjy_empresas.bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira";
      // Executa a consulta OU mostra uma mensagem de erro
      $rs = $MySQLi->query($qry) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);

      // Faz um loop, passando por todos os resultados encontrados              
      while ($dt        = $rs->fetch_object()) {
            $band       = $dt->id_bandeira;
            $bandeira   = $dt->bandeira;


            echo "<option value='premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha&bandorc=$band' ".($bandorc==$band?"selected":"").">$bandeira</option>";
    }
?>  
            </select> 
        <!--</form>-->
        </td>
    <td width="*">      

<!---   <form method="get" name="tLoja" id="cLoja" style="float:left; padding-left:15px;margin-top:0px;"> -->
            <select name="menu2" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
                <option value="">Selecione primeiro a Bandeira</option>
            <?php   
    $sql="SELECT sjy_empresas.id_empresa, sjy_empresas.nick, sjy_empresas.bandeira
            FROM sjy_empresas
            WHERE sjy_empresas.grupo = $grupo
            AND bandeira = $bandorc";
      // Executa a consulta OU mostra uma mensagem de erro
      $rset = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);

      // Faz um loop, passando por todos os resultados encontrados              
      while ($dt        = $rset->fetch_object()) {
            $emprsel        = $dt->id_empresa;
            $nicksel        = $dt->nick;
            echo    "<option value='premorc.php?fnc=". $fnc . "&ans=" . $linha . "&emp=" . $emprsel . "'>" . $nicksel . "</option>";
            }

            ?>

            </select>           
        </form>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>

    <form action="../inc/processa.php" method="post">
        <input name="emp" type="text" value="<?php echo $emprsel; ?>" /> - Filial da Premissa: <?php echo $nicksel; ?>

    </form>
```

Comment: E o jQuery que faz isso? Onde está?

Comment: Olá André. Obrigado pela resposta. Editei a pergunta para que agora contemplasse o JQuery